# How to add a watermark image to Qweb Reports in all PDF pages in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, watermark, qweb

I am creating qweb report and I want to add a image to the background in all pages but I am getting watermark in only the first page. What I have tried:

```html
<div style="position:absolute;text-align:center;z-index:-1;border:0;opacity:0.1;padding-top:50px;">
    <img t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,%s' %o.employee_id.company_id.watermark_img"/>
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="page">
<div
                                style="position:absolute;text-align:center;z-index:-1;border:0;opacity:0.1;padding-top:50px;">
                                <img t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,%s' %o.employee_id.company_id.watermark_img"/>
                            </div>
</div>

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution [here](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/question/how-to-add-watermark-on-every-page-of-qweb-report-113382)

Add this code for watermark in header of external layout. Its external id is `report.external_layout_header`:

```html
<style>
    .watermark {
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0.25;
        z-index: 1000;
        transform: rotate(300deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg);
        width: 150%;
    }
</style>

<div class="watermark">
    <p>WATERMARK</p>
    <img t-att-src="'/module_name/static/src/img/image_name.png'" />
</div>
```

I have added a image stored as a file. If you are going to use a static image I think this is the most appropiate way

**Note**: I am afraid this does not work in Odoo v11

### Update

This solution only is valid if you want to add the same image to all the reports.

There is a module developed by the OCA to add watermarks to the reports. A field appears in all reports where an images (with A4 size) can be added. The module name is [`report_qweb_pdf_watermark`](https://github.com/OCA/reporting-engine/tree/11.0)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code:

```
<div 
style="position:absolute;opacity:0.25;z-index:1000;transform:rotate(300deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(300deg);width:150%;">
<p style="font-size:50px;">WATERMARK TEXT</p>
</div>
```