# How to add watermarks in all pages of Odoo Reports?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, qweb

Using below code It is just view on the first page. I want to show watermark on all pages.

```
<div class="watermark_report">
    <img t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,'+ doc.company_id.report_header_logo"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have the answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49160954/4891717):

Add this code for watermark in header of external layout. Its external id is `report.external_layout_header`:

```html
<style>
    .watermark {
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0.25;
        z-index: 1000;
        transform: rotate(300deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg);
        width: 150%;
    }
</style>

<div class="watermark">
    <p>WATERMARK</p>
    <img t-att-src="'/module_name/static/src/img/image_name.png'" />
</div>
```

I have added a image stored as a file. If you are going to use a static image I think this is the most appropriate way

**Note**: Instead of using the css attribute `opacity` you can use a png image with opacity and transparent backgroud. That´s what I had to do

**Note 2**: I am afraid this does not work in Odoo v11

### Update

This solution only is valid if you want to add the same image to all the reports.

There is a module developed by the OCA to add watermarks to the reports. A field appears in all reports where an images (with A4 size) can be added. The module name is [`report_qweb_pdf_watermark`](https://github.com/OCA/reporting-engine/tree/11.0)