# How to add watermarks in all pages of Odoo 11 Reports?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-11, qweb

I want to show watermark on all pages in odoo 11. i have tried this [How to add watermarks in all pages of Odoo Reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49426352/how-to-add-watermarks-in-all-pages-of-odoo-reports)
but doesn't work with odoo 11. So how to add watermarks in all pages of Odoo 11 Reports?

Answer (score 1):

Please check [Reports with Watermark](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/11.0/reports_with_watermark/) module for Odoo v11. with the configuration on the company record, you can enable the watermark on the pdf reports throughout Odoo.

hope this helps!

Comment: Or you can add via css also.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this example

```
<style>
.watermark {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.25;
    z-index: 1000;
    transform: rotate(300deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg);
    width: 150%;
}
```

```
<div class="watermark">
<p>WATERMARK</p>
<img t-att-. src="'/module_name/static/src/img/image_name.png'" />
</div>
```